# How to change background color and image of the button onpress which is dynamically rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a project by using react native. I used map function to render the buttons. when the page loads first button want to be in blue color and remaining want to be in white color. Once the next button is clicked previous button color and image want to be changed. Pressed button want to be in blue color. As of now when I clicked the first button remaining button colors is also changing. Any body can correct me where I went wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      prd: [],
      on: false,
      prdData: "All",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    let data = [
      {
        id: 0,
        value: "All",
        img1: require("../../../kr/images/all_white.png"),
        img2: require("../../../kr/images/all_blue.png"),
      },
      {
        id: 41,
        value: "list",
        img1: require("../../../kr/images/package_white.png"),
        img2: require("../../../kr/images/package_blue.png"),
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        value: "list2",
        img1: require("../../../kr/images/accident_white.png"),
        img2: require("../../../kr/images/accident_blue.png"),
      },
      { id: 14, value: "Term" },
    ];
    this.setState({ prd: data });
  }

 render() {
    const { on } = this.state;
    return (
<View>
            {/* Button contain starts */}
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              >
                {this.state.product.map((item, i) => {
                  return (
                    <Button
                      onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({ on: !this.state.on });
                      }}
                      style={on ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnNonActive}
                    >
                      <Image
                        style={{
                          width: 18,
                          height: 17,
                          flex: 1,
                          flexDirection: "row",
                          backgroundColor: "white",
                        }}
                        source={
                          this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? item.img1 : item.img2
                        }
                      />{" "}
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          color: "black",
                          fontSize: 11,
                          flex: 1,
                          flexDirection: "row",
                        }}
                      >
                        {item.value}
                      </Text>
                    </Button>
                  );
                })}
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
)
```

Comment: create separate component for making item in it create state for the button click as of now all the item buttons are using the same state

Answer (score 0):

Create a Item Component and handle color change state in int, don't use I the main component,

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/grounded-cookie

Here is an example,

```
const data = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog'];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <Item
            key={item}
            item={item}
            onPress={() => {
              console.log(item);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const Item = ({ item, onPress }) => {
  const [on, setOn] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text>{item}</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => {
          setOn(true);
          onPress();
        }}
        style={[styles.button, on && styles.activeBuyton]}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>Click</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  item: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    height: 100,
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#00000010',
  },
  button: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    height: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  activeBuyton: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});
```